# Python - Capturing stdout of a multiple Popen subprocesses in real time to a file

Tags: python, subprocess

I am able to capture the output of a processed called by '`Popen` in real time using the following code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,''):
    sys.stdout.write(line)

output, error = p.communicate()
```

This works great. However, I now have multiple processes running using the code below, so I need to capture the stdout to a file for each process:

```
for mapped_file in range(1,3):

    #Fire the command in parallel
    stdout = open(outfile + '.stdout', 'w')
    p = subprocess.Popen(args,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    stdout_list.append(stdout)
    process_list.append(p)

    #for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,''):
    #   stdout.write(line)

    #Wait for all processes to continue
    while len(process_list) > 0:
        for process in process_list:

        #Loop through the process to wait until all tasks finished
        if not process.poll() is None:
            output, error = process.communicate()

            #Remove the process from the list because it has finished
            process_list.remove(process)

        #Sleep for 1 second in between iterations
        time.sleep(1)
```

Including `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,''):...` code keeps the code executing in the first loop only.

**How can I capture the `stdout` (and presumably the `stderr`) in real time of each process executed inside my loop to a file?**

Comment: your first code example may deadlock if the child process would produce enough output on stderr. The second code example may deadlock if *any* child process produces enough output on stdout *or* stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a new file object to `subprocess.Popen` each time you call it. This allows you to divert `stdout`  to a separate file for each process. Here is an example

```
import subprocess


procs = []

for p in range(3):
        args = ['echo',"A Message from process #%d" % p]
        #Funnel stdout to a file object, using buffering
        fout = open("stdout_%d.txt" % p,'w')
        p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=fout,bufsize=-1)
        procs.append(p)

#Wait for all to finish
for p in procs:
    p.communicate()
```

When I run that I get 3 separate files

```
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~/Documents$ python write_multiple_proc_to_file.py 
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~/Documents$ ls -l stdout_*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ericu ericu 26 Feb 23 09:59 stdout_0.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ericu ericu 26 Feb 23 09:59 stdout_1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ericu ericu 26 Feb 23 09:59 stdout_2.txt
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~/Documents$ cat stdout_*.txt
A Message from process #0
A Message from process #1
A Message from process #2
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~/Documents$
```

Comment: I needed to add the `bufsize` keyword to really see the realtime. Thanks!!! Works perfect.

Comment: +1 for `stdout=file`. Call `fout.close()` after `Popen()` (you don't need the file to be opened in the parent). It is pointless to call `p.communicate()` (`PIPE` is not used). `p.wait()` is more appropriate here.

Comment: @Brett: `bufsize` is useless here (`PIPE` is not used). `stdout=file` works at the level of file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

Popen's stdin and stdout arguments accept file objects so you could just pass the opened file in there.

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects):

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard
>   input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively.
>   Valid values are PIPE, an existing file descriptor (a positive
>   integer), **an existing file object**, and None. PIPE indicates that a new
>   pipe to the child should be created. [...]